# "unable to execute /bin/bash"

Tags: bash, sudo, ldap

We have Ldap running in our environment. Particular user X is provided sudo access on another Y. But when X tries command **"sudo -u Y -I"**. System asks for passwd, after entering the passwd it throws an error **"unable to execute /bin/bash as Y"**. But for the same Y user other user who are granted access to do sudo are able to perform same action without any issue. **Problem seems to be only for X user, also for him also settings were working fine but from last couple he is facing this issue.**

Thanks!

Comment: Please add output of `type bash`.

Answer (score 0):

On debian `bash` is in `/usr/bin/bash`. It is probably a problem with the users default shell in `/etc/passwd`.